# Saving a value even after program is closed and reopened

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

I would like to know  how  to save the contents of a "variable"  after program is closed and reopened.

for eg:
iCount:=0;
inc(iCount)=1;

when i close the program and reopen i want iCount to contain 1.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You need to save the value somewhere: in a file, in the Windows registry, in the cloud, ...

## File

Perhaps the easiest approach is to use an INI file. Try this:

1. Create a new VCL application.
2. Add a field `FMyNumber: Integer` to the main form.
3. To the main form, add the following methods (and make sure to include `IniFiles` and `IOUtils` in the implementation section's `uses` list):

   ```
   function TForm1.GetSettingsFileName: TFileName;
   begin
     Result := TPath.GetHomePath + '\Fuzail\TestApp';
     ForceDirectories(Result);
     Result := Result + '\settings.ini';
   end;

   procedure TForm1.LoadSettings;
   var
     Ini: TMemIniFile;
   begin
     Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(GetSettingsFileName);
     try
       FMyNumber := Ini.ReadInteger('Settings', 'MyNumber', 0);
     finally
       Ini.Free;
     end;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.SaveSettings;
   var
     Ini: TMemIniFile;
   begin
     Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(GetSettingsFileName);
     try
       Ini.WriteInteger('Settings', 'MyNumber', FMyNumber);
       Ini.UpdateFile;
     finally
       Ini.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```
4. Now make sure to call these when your application is starting and shutting down:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     LoadSettings;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     SaveSettings;
   end;
   ```

   Now the value of `FMyNumber` is saved between the sessions!

## Registry

Another common approach, probably, is to use the registry. Try this:

1. Create a new VCL application.
2. Add a field `FMyNumber: Integer` to the main form.
3. To the main form, add the following methods (and make sure to include `Registry` in the implementation section's `uses` list):

   ```
   procedure TForm1.LoadSettings;
   var
     Reg: TRegistry;
   begin
     Reg := TRegistry.Create;
     try
       Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
       if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Fuzail\TestApp', False) then
         try
           if Reg.ValueExists('MyNumber') then
             FMyNumber := Reg.ReadInteger('MyNumber')
         finally
           Reg.CloseKey;
         end;
     finally
       Reg.Free;
     end;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.SaveSettings;
   var
     Reg: TRegistry;
   begin
     Reg := TRegistry.Create;
     try
       Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
       if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Fuzail\TestApp', True) then
         try
           Reg.WriteInteger('MyNumber', FMyNumber);
         finally
           Reg.CloseKey;
         end;
     finally
       Reg.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```
4. Now make sure to call these when your application is starting and shutting down:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     LoadSettings;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     SaveSettings;
   end;
   ```

   Again the value of `FMyNumber` is saved between the sessions!

Comment: Um, any reason for suggesting the registry rather than an IniFile (I thought even MS now discourage the use of the registry (imo the biggest architectural folly of all time) for this sort of thing)?

Comment: @MartynA: I kind of like the registry for convenient but not super-important per-user settings like GUI states, but in the end it is the specific scenario that determines what storage method is the most appropriate, and the Q doesn't contain any such details.

Comment: Agreed with @MartynA, I would avoid using the registry in new applications (other than for things which require registry interaction).  For user settings, config files, etc, the correct place to store these are the appropriate AppData folders.

Comment: Bravo for the addition. +1

Comment: IMO; Registry is useful when you want to deploy a program which configuration could be erased by error (Like an INI file). Most of final users could be able to delete this file by error, but not able to go to registry, find whatever and erase it: I normally use it for parameters that I don't want to be so available for users